# How to allow line breaks after forward slashes in ConTeXt?

Tags: line-breaking, context

I have a document containing many forward slashes (`/`). I noticed that ConTeXt does not allow breaks after `/`. For instance, if a text contains `bear/rabbit/tiger`, it will not place a break and the text will flow off the edge into the margins.

- How can I create a special environment, inside of which, the rules for line breaking allows a line break after a `/`, if deemed necessary, with slightly higher or equal preference to what is given to a space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\setbreakpoints` is made for that. Setting `\setbreakpoints [compound]` enables a break point after `/`, `+`, `(`, `)` and `-`. For more information see [ConTeXt wiki Composed words](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Composed_words).

Example:

```
\setuplayout [width=4cm]
\starttext

Lorem/ipsum/dolor/sit/amet,/consectetur/adipisicing/elit,/sed/%
do/eiusmod/tempor/incididunt/ut/labore/et/dolore/magna/aliqua.

\setbreakpoints [compound]
\blank

Lorem/ipsum/dolor/sit/amet,/consectetur/adipisicing/elit,/sed/%
do/eiusmod/tempor/incididunt/ut/labore/et/dolore/magna/aliqua.

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: If I want some block of text to behave in this way, but the rest of the document not to, how do I ensure only that part has this kind of line breaks?

Comment: Set `\setbreakpoints[compound]` in a group (between `{...}` or `\bgroup ... \egroup` or `\begingroup ... \endgroup`. If this is part of an environment, you should be able to use the `setups` key.